# Query that should pull unsubscribed records from SF into MC fails

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

We have an automation in Marketing Cloud, that daily is running a query that is supposed to pull all records that are unsubscribed from SF into a data extension in MC.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
[_ContactKey] AS [Subscriber Key]
, [Email] AS [Email Address] 
FROM [Contact_Salesforce] 
WHERE [Marketing_permission_Email__c] = 0
```

The data extension has these fields:
`Subscriber Key`, `Email Address`, `Status`

(`Subsriber Key` is primary key)

The query worked fine until last of May, and starting failing each day from June 1st.

Any ideas at all?

Wrong query or has there been a release causing this?

Comment: What is the Primary Key in you Contact_Salesforce Data Extension? Is this a Data Streamed object? If so, what's the formula behind "_ContactKey"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "ent." prefix for the Synchronized DE - not sure exactly why that is, but it is a given. See query below:

```
SELECT [_ContactKey] AS [Subscriber Key]
,[Email] AS [Email Address] 
FROM ent.[Contact_Salesforce] 
WHERE [Marketing_permission_Email__c] = 0
```

A simpler way to write the query is this (also - are there spaces in your subscriber key and email address fields in the target data extension?):

```
SELECT _ContactKey AS [Subscriber Key]
,Email AS [Email Address] 
FROM ent.Contact_Salesforce
WHERE Marketing_permission_Email__c = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Keneth, but I get an error: "The [ent.Contact_Salesforce] table has a multi-part specification. This is not allowed.
[ent.Contact_Salesforce] is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query existing data extensions or system data views."
Might be due to that this is not enterprise account?....by the way - it is not a syncronized DE that is ued - maybe we should use such instead?

Comment: Hmm it might be - in that case, it might be a matter of simply replacing _ContacKey with Id in your original query :)

Comment: You were of course right, it is syncronized data extension as data source/datastream. Still no luck. Tested to query the default "HasOptedOutOfEmail" but also with no luck (tried using Id as you suggested) but the the query continues doing nothing. Seems like a problem beyond reach.

Comment: Hmm... i am busy rest of today - Could you share screenshots of DE to my mail: Kenn.wagner@gmail.com ?

Comment: Prefix syntax should be `ent.[Contact_Salesforce]` or simply `ent.Contact_Salesforce`.